How to change a method from synchronous to asynchronous via byte-buddy？
public class ByteBuddyExample {
    public static class Foo {
        public void performTask() {
            System.out.println("Performing task...");
        }
    }

    public static class AsyncAdvice {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter(skipOn = Advice.OnNonDefaultValue.class)
        public static boolean enter(@Advice.This Foo foo, @Advice.Origin Method method) {
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runAsyncMethod(foo, method);
                }
            });
            return true;
        }

        public static void runAsyncMethod(Foo foo, Method method) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Async task started...");
                method.invoke(foo);
                System.out.println("Async task completed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ByteBuddyAgent.install();

        new ByteBuddy().rebase(Foo.class)
            .visit(Advice.to(AsyncAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.named("performTask")))
            .make()
            .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent())
            .saveIn(new File("./"));

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.performTask();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}

The preceding code causes the problem that performTask is invoked cyclically.
I understand that ByteBuddy ().rebase () will modify the original method to private decoration and change the name, and then generate a new performTask method, but after saving the bytecode, it is found that the original method is modified.  What am I supposed to do?
How should I implement the above idea?

Add a ThreadLocal<Boolean> which you set to true in runAsyncMethod. In the advice, you check if the ThreadLocal is set to true. If so, you set it back to false but also return false from the advice so that the original code is not skipped for this particular execution.
